# How to filter a list according to filter list except of item on another list?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have some algorithmic challange:

Suppose I have the following list of strings:

```
{"South", "East", "West", "North"}
```

Now, I have a stream of items as an input.

For example:

```
{"South", "North korea", "East", "South carolina", "West", "North"}
```

As a general rule, I want to remove all the stream items which contains the items in the first list.

But there may be some exceptions.
The exceptions might be set in another list.
For example:

```
{"South korea", "North korea"}
```

etc.

Notice, the exceptions list can include a large number of items, so I don't want to test each one of items implicitly.

On the other hand, I wouldn't like to have south carolina on the output list, but only the ones that in the excptions listm, and of course the ones that are not part of the first list.

So, the output of the above example should be:

```
{"North korea"}
```

I tried something like this (and some more variations) but obviously it isn't correct (Java):

```
    return
            Arrays.stream(illegalWordList).noneMatch(word::contains) &&
            Arrays.stream(excludedFromIllegalWordsList).noneMatch(word::contains);
```

Can you assist please?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question may get more attention when you tag it with the programming language.

Comment: I really had a dillema about that. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: In your text you say you want to filter out blacklisted items, but your code looks like you want to filter out items, which contain blacklisted text. Which one is it? Same for the whitelist.

Comment: @F43nd1r There are some strings that I'd like to remove, and they are on the first list. However, these strings may be part of other string, which some of them I'd like to keep and some of them to filter out. As in the example above: I'd like to filter out all the strings which contain "South" and "North". Still, if the strings are "North Korea" or "South Korea", as listed in the second list, I don't want to throw them out of the output. I hope it is understood better now :)

Comment: Please post a clear example of all the input lists and the stream and the expected output, explaining why the output is generated that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but to me it seems like you're close to a correct solution, just some flipped logic. Try

```
Arrays.stream(words).filter(word => {
    return Arrays.stream(illegalWordList).noneMatch(word::contains) 
        || Arrays.stream(excludedFromIllegalWordsList).anyMatch(word::contains)
    })
```

This essentially says "keep all items that don't contain anything blacklisted, or contain anything whitelisted"

Comment: Thank you. 
And if I may I'd like to modify a bit my question: I'd like to know if a given string is "valid". Meaning: Not illegal according to the illegalWordList but can be also part of the exclusions list. I want to have a boolean answer for that. 
For example, if my input is "North Korea" I should get true, and if my input is "North Vietnam" I'll get false.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Just take the inner part of filter, it is a boolean value and meets your criteria.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it in my code and update.

Comment: Thank you my friend. It worked. I was really close, but you pinned point the solution for me :)